# End-user Admin Consent Request vs "Need admin approval"

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have an application in Microsoft's appSource (aka Store). We'd like for end-users to be able to request admin consent from tenant admins when we detect that the admin hasn't accepted our perms in a specific workflow. When the non-admin end-user clicks this url: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id={app-id}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&redirect_uri={endpoint}&state={some](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id%7D/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=%7Bapp-id%7D&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&redirect_uri=%7Bendpoint%7D&state=%7Bsome) nounce} they see

[image]

**Some of our installs are large enterprises so the end-user won't know who their Global Tenant Admin is, so we'd like for the end user to have this experience instead:**

[image]

Our permissions requested are:

[image]

I've followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow#enable-the-admin-consent-workflow and have allowed users to request consent.  I've also checked AAD audit logs and if a clue is there, it's not jumping out at me.  We suspect the Application permission TeamsActivity.send is the culprit but we don't understand why.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sharon

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application and added API permissions** like below:

[image]

I configured the **Admin Consent Flow**:

[image]

When I tried to **grant admin consent** by using the below URL, I got the error like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&state=12345
```

[image]

> **Note** that: A Global administrator's approval is always required for application permissions (App-only) access.

- An error occurs stating that the user is unable to consent if your application requests an app-only permission and the user attempts to sign into the application.

So, to grant admin **consent to Application permissions**, you have to sign-in as **`Global Administrator`** and a consent screen will appear like below:

[image]

A user gets the **Approval required screen** for the delegated permissions while signing-in:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/fb134080-e4d2-45f4-9562-f3a0c218f3b0/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=4ac92ddf-4966-4bc6-ac04-7628b6c0bab9
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

[image]

The admin gets the request and can accept the consent like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It sounds like we're out of luck as a Global Admin must consent first in order for the consent workflow to operate as we hoped.  Our issue is in a large organization, if the global admin has not consented to the app permissions, the end users gets the error page "Need admin approval", but they don't know who their global admin is.

Comment: By default it works as detailed by me in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

testruk's answer is correct. Use the /authorize endpoint.  /adminconsent seems limited. /authorize wasn't working for me because I needed to "unconsent" to permissions.  The easiest way to do that is to delete the Enterprise App that's created when you install the add-in to your tenant.  Also, the scope query param only seems to support delegated permissions, which is unfortunate for our use-case.